# /Zc:wchar_t how to use it as unsigned int and builtin type at the same time due to multiple libraries compiled using different options

Tags: visual-c++, firefox-addon

Firefox has changed usage of /Zc:wchar_t- for Gecko 7+

Have a bunch of other libraries using this setting also which was convenient previously, but now they are in conflict it seems to be a world of pain.

Any recommendations for how to include headers so that we can use `wchar_t` as a built in type and also as `unsigned int` at the same time in the same C++ module?

Comment: Well, good reason to finally drop this bad habit.

Comment: Uhm, yeah, sure... just like nobody is using java 1.1 applets anymore.  We have an existing technology stack that uses it that is not insignificant and will take time to convert.  Some of it we have tried already and it didn't convert well, so it will be a time consuming job to complete.  It would be nice if somebody knew of an option to allow a progressive conversion to make it manageable.